# Javascript SVG dragging

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events, coordinate-transformation

The original question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055607/trying-to-rotate-and-transform-svg-path-do-i-need-trigonometry-calculations

...I'm trying to figure out how could I drag another point of resistor:
http://www.3lectronics.com/electronics-layout/resistor.svg

SVG events, parent, child and other family takes time for me to getting know about.

If someone want to help...

Comment: Or this question could have been added as a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have something like what you're asking for at: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/169269/resistor2.svg
It should get you started anyway.

It's a lot more complicated now, but should make it easier to add more elements. I suspect there must be an easier way, but it's an interesting challenge. It now uses matrix transformations, which I think are necessary (so you need to learn them if you don't already know them) as you need to keep track of previous transformations. I recommend looking at http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#NestedTransformations

The new drag function looks like this:

```
function drag(evt)
{
    if(selected_element != 0)
    {
        dx = rotate_x - evt.pageX;
        dy = rotate_y - evt.pageY;

        new_size  = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) / element_size;
        new_angle = Math.PI/2 + Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        delta_size  = new_size / current_size;
        delta_angle = new_angle - current_angle;
        current_size  = new_size;
        current_angle = new_angle;

        new_matrix = new Array(6);

        // Scale
        for (i=0; i<6; i++){
            current_matrix[i] = current_matrix[i] * delta_size;
        }
        current_matrix[4] = current_matrix[4] + (-delta_size) * rotate_x;
        current_matrix[5] = current_matrix[5] + (-delta_size) * rotate_y;


        for (i=0; i<6; i++){new_matrix[i] = current_matrix[i]; }

        // Rotate around (0,0)
        cos_theta = Math.cos(delta_angle);
        sin_theta = Math.sin(delta_angle);
        new_matrix[0] = cos_theta*current_matrix[0] - sin_theta*current_matrix[1];
        new_matrix[1] = sin_theta*current_matrix[0] + cos_theta*current_matrix[1];
        new_matrix[2] = cos_theta*current_matrix[2] - sin_theta*current_matrix[3];
        new_matrix[3] = sin_theta*current_matrix[2] + cos_theta*current_matrix[3];
        new_matrix[4] = cos_theta*current_matrix[4] - sin_theta*current_matrix[5];
        new_matrix[5] = sin_theta*current_matrix[4] + cos_theta*current_matrix[5];

        // Transform back to original point
        new_matrix[4] += rotate_x;
        new_matrix[5] += rotate_y;

        transform = "matrix(" + new_matrix.join(' ') + ")" ;
        selected_element.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", transform);
        current_matrix = new_matrix;
    }
}
```

It's similar to before only now it measures the difference in angle and distance since the last drag event.

The resistor group looks like:

```
  <g class="resistor" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" onmouseup="deselectElement()" size="200">
    <line x1="200" y1="200" x2="200" y2="400" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" pointer-events="none"/>
    <rect x="180" y="250" width="40" height="100" stroke="blue" fill="white" stroke-width="5" pointer-events="none"/>
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="10" fill="blue" onmousedown="selectElement(evt, 200, 400)"/> 
    <circle cx="200" cy="400" r="10" fill="blue" onmousedown="selectElement(evt, 200, 200)"/> 
  </g>
```

The important points to notice is that the main group has a size attribute which tells the function how long the resistor should be. The circles have selectElement functions and pass the coordinates of the other circle to indicate that rotations and scaling should be about this point. I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm also sure that everything has the better way to do, but your effort open my mind about what should have to do about this and other similar problems. Remember, I'm just starting with JS and SVG and practical examples are invaluable lessons for me to learn how to approach some issue.

Comment: BTW this code works only with Chrome (on my Linux Mint) and I started Chrome's JS console which gives me: "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml.". Also it makes indents of its own. I copy that same code with those indentation as resistor3.svg and now runs in Opera and Midori (still not in Firefox)?! Some silly browser rules!

(http://www.3lectronics.com/electronics-layout/resistor3.svg)

Comment: Please don't bother with that, I have enough staff for practicing and you did me a huge favor.
How can I repay you? If you'll go to Adriatic coast I will gladly ask my friends to give you accommodation for a while in some apartment near the beach (near Split-Croatia). Also  maybe can help you with electronics design if you need it.
Don't hesitate.

Thanks a huge!

Comment: Glad I could be of some help. It looks like an interesting project. It was fun to mess about with. I think I might be able to do it a simpler way some time. I didn't test it outside of Chrome, not sure why it doesn't work on Firefox. I don't think you need to worry about "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml.".

Comment: I visited your blog which I consider as very interesting, design is optimistic and nice. Good job. About Firefox problem, I found that attribute tag: size= is not valid for SVG. Project is for me very much interesting, some beginning you can see at (http://www.3lectronics.com/electronics-layout/Atarado-Draw1.html), and I have to learn SVG wich make it sense. I'm also trilled of upgrading it with schematics interaction, autoroute, autoplacement...but it will take a time. I would be glad to help you in any way I could. Stay well.